# perl cgi::param error with single plus sign in Taint mode

Tags: perl, cgi, param, taint

I work on a website based on Perl CGI. It's run with Perl -T (Taint mode). I noticed that a text input contains just a plus sign and nothing else ("+") causes CGI::param() to give this error:

Insecure dependency in require while running with -T switch at ....../CGI.pm line 533.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

This does not apply to other single signs, or a plus sign with leading or trailing blanks ("-", " + ", "?").

Although users usually won't enter a single plus sign as input, I would like to have a workaround here so that my script will reject the input nicely, instead of printing an ugly "Software Error" in the browser.

```
REQUEST_METHOD=GET QUERY_STRING='page=%2B' perl -s -T -E'
use strict;
use CGI qw( :standard  );
CGI->new();
my $page;
eval { $page = param("page"); };
print "[ $@ ]\n";
```

'

This prints a compilation error:

[ Insecure dependency in require while running with -T switch at ../..../CGI.pm line xxx.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
 ]

If I skip CGI->new() there will be no error. But this is not an option according to our requirements.

I hope this is more clear. Thanks all for being helpful!

YJ

Comment: "+" is used to indicate a space in URLs.
It is needed to be encoded to "%2B" if "+" is meant.
So you want to check the case if a user just sends a space?

Comment: Hi Boris,Not quite. I have no control over what the user sends. But I want to make sure that the website handles user input "+" (with no whitespace) nicely. Even if "+" should be rejected, I don't want it to look like my website is broken.

Comment: Perhaps you should show some code that concerns what you are talking about.

Comment: I tried reproducing the problem, but my test script accepted `%2B` in taint mode when I called `param` without complaint.

Comment: @user1970978 – I put `%2B` in the URL. It is what you get when you submit a form with a field containing a `+`.

Comment: What's your version of CGI? (`perl -e'use CGI 999'` will mention it)

Comment: ...and your Perl version.

Comment: @ikegami perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi. CGI version 3.43.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a CGI object, use it.

```
my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $page = $cgi->param("page");
```

or

```
param("page");
```

but don't mix and match.

Comment: I did what you suggested and the problem is gone. Could you please elaborate a little bit (or point me to some readings) on how exactly the error arises? That'd be very helpful.

Comment: The problem is caused by attempting to parse the request twice, but for why that that gives that error specifically, you'll have to trace through CGI.pm